# How to substract two lists of lists from each other?

Tags: python, list

I have the following two list of lists and I want to substract every item from a from the corresponding item in b:

```py
a = [[8.5], [9.3], [8.2]]
b = [[7.4], [2.3], [3.4]]
```

So the output should be

```py
c = [[1.1], [7], [4.8]]
```

It seems to be very simple, but I am struggling with it. Does somebody have a solution?

Comment: `c =[[i[0]-j[0]] for i,j in zip(a,b)]`

Comment: `import numpy as np; np.subtract(a, b)`

Answer (score 1):

Create flat list of both first

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
```

then convert to numpy array

```
a= np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
```

then make list of lists `[i for i in a]` and similarly b

Comment: why to create a flat list, then use numpy to substract, then change back to OP output format, when all this you can do in single list comprehension ?